# How to pass data from ordinary class members to WCF DataMembers?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, serialization

How to assign the values of my ordinary class's member to WCF DataContract DataMember.
Basically I want to save some data from UI to Database. Now UI is having a class Customer which has member as CustomerName which I am getting from UI.Now through services I am sending those value of CustomerName to my Service layer.There is class Customer whose attribute is [DataContract] and member as CustomerName which has attribute DataMember.Now my question is how to convert those ordinary CustomerName to CustomerName of service(which are having attributes DataMember).

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is very confusing. DataMember is just an attribute on a normal class so you should very easily be able to set the properties.

Comment: you are right Ross but one class is in WcfServiceLibrary Project and each of them have a member associated with attribute [DataMember].Now from UI I am getting the value.Now that value is stored in  a ordinary class's Datamember .Now my question is how to convert that is Customer.CompanyName(this is my WCF class member)=Customer.CompanyName ;

Answer (score 0):

You need a mapping layer\tool. Have a look at auto mapping tools like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) which can easily do the heavy lifting of mapping entities.